# Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file: * Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - Expected string, received undefined

Tags: blockchain

I have this code in .env

```
API_URL = "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/<API>"
PRIVATE_KEY = "6**********2a4********************7b96***********5af*****1"
```

But when I run this hardhat.config.js file

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")

require("dotenv").config()

const SEP_API_URL = process.env.API_URL

const SEP_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */

module.exports = {

    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",

    networks: {

        Sepolia: {

            url: SEP_API_URL,

            accounts: [SEP_PRIVATE_KEY],

            chainId: 11155111,

        },

    },

    solidity: "0.7.3",

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - Expected string, received undefined
```

Comment: Did you use the private key with `0x` prefix? If one doesn't work try the other option.

Answer (score 0):

Do these:

First, use `console.log(SEP_PRIVATE_KEY);` to check if it's there or not.

Second, remove the double quotes for the private key in the ENV file.